# Laravel query builder join with raw ON expression

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to achieve something like the following simplified example in Laravel 5.5 Query builder:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
INNER JOIN access
  ON (t.field1 = access.field1 OR t.field2 = access.field2)
     AND access.user_id = :user_id
```

Note that the ON has a compound expression on multiple fields and also uses a parameter.

I'm really struggling to get the ON statement to work. I've tried every combination of `join()` and `DB:raw()` I can think of.

How can this be achieved with Laravel's query builder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DB::table('t')->join('access', function($query) use($user_id) {
    $query->where(function($query) {
        $query->on('t.field1', '=', 'access.field1')
            ->orOn('t.field2', '=', 'access.path_field2');
    })->where('access.user_id', '=', $user_id);
});
```

The `->where('access.user_id', '=', $user_id)` condition doesn't have to be inside the JOIN closure. I just put it there to exactly match your query. Placing it outside simplifies the code:

```
DB::table('t')->join('access', function($query) {
    $query->on('t.field1', '=', 'access.field1')
        ->orOn('t.field2', '=', 'access.path_field2');
})->where('access.user_id', '=', $user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had missed the use of `where` in join callbacks to specify a value instead of a column. I had assumed `where` would, you know, add to the where clause as in your 2nd example. Of course in this simple example your 2 helpful examples are identical in result but in some cases conditions in `on` have different effect.